# How to keep the session open in tcl http

Tags: tcl

Using tcl http package I am connecting to url with the credentials required. After that I want to send a query, but geturl proc doesn't have an option to use existing token id.

```
set auth "Basic [base64::encode test:test123]"
set headerl [list Authorization $auth]
set tok [http::geturl http://192.168.2.77:9001 -headers $headerl -timeout 10000 -type text/html]
http::wait $tok
if {![string compare [http::status $tok] "ok"]} {
    puts [http::data $tok]
} else {
    puts stderr [http::error $tok]
}
```

Here I want to send a query for the subsequent page, but i couldn't find an option to do that

If I do geturl again then it is throwing error saying that authorization failed.

```
set tok [http::geturl http://192.168.4.77:9001/index.html?action=stopall -timeout 10000 -type text/html]
http::wait $tok
if {![string compare [http::status $tok] "ok"]} {
    puts [http::data $tok]
} else {
    puts stderr [http::error $tok]
}

<head>
<title>Error response</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Error response</h1>
<p>Error code 401.
<p>Message: Unauthorized.
</body>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Always use `-keepalive`

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn with the -keepalive I can keep the session open, but how to interact with that session ?
Thanks for your reply

Comment: What's the simplest thing that could possibly work? Have you tried just making more requests to the same host?

Comment: @Donal Fellows I have updated the the question with the response received after making next query.

Comment: Don't you need the `-headers` still in your subsequent calls!? Or catch some session id from the cookies corresponding to the first call to include?

Comment: Including the authorization header in the next request served my purpose.
Thanks @Captain

Comment: while this works well for basic authentification, the overhead for Kerberos/NTLM is higher, so servers that accept them usually use the authentification from earlier request from the socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a cookie jar for holding the response cookies.  Here's an example that adds cookies to a jar and sends them back.  Be aware that it doesn't check cookie attributes which you need to do to avoid exposing session keys.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

package require http

proc wget {url {jarname COOKIE_JAR}} {

    set o_headers {User-Agent {Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)}}
    upvar $jarname cookiejar
    set cookies [list]

    # WARNING - Blindly sending cookies in jar. You chould check attributes.
    # domain, path, expires, httponly, secure, max-age

    # Adding cookiename=value without attributes. Attributes aren't for sending.
    foreach {value} $cookiejar {lappend cookies [lindex [split $value ";"] 0]}

    # Add cookies to the header.
    lappend o_headers "Cookie" [join $cookies "; "]

    set tok [::http::geturl $url -timeout 10000 -method GET -query "" -headers $o_headers]

    # add/replace cookies in the return headers.
    foreach {key value} [::http::meta $tok] {
        if {[string tolower $key] != "set-cookie"} {continue}

        set cookie_key [lindex [regexp -inline {\s*([^=]+)} $value] 1]

        if {[set index [lsearch -glob $cookiejar "$cookie_key=*"]] != -1} {
            # Replace if cookie already exists
            lset cookiejar $index $value
            continue
        }

        lappend cookiejar $value
    }

    return [::http::data $tok]
}

set google_cookies [list]
set page http://www.google.com
puts "Cookies before request.\n$google_cookies"
wget $page google_cookies
puts "Cookies after request.\n$google_cookies"
```

Output:

```
./wget
Cookies before request.

Cookies after request.
{PREF=ID=xxx:FF=0:TM=xxx:LM=xx:S=xxx-xxx; expires=Sun, 18-Dec-2016 02:26:37 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com} {NID=12=x_xx_xxx-xxxx_xxxxx; expires=Sat, 20-Jun-2015 02:26:37 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly}
```